# How to select columns whose names are in a column from another table?

Tags: select, proc-sql

In a PROC SQL how to do this?

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE SASUSER.COLS (
    COL VARCHAR(20)
    );

INSERT INTO SASUSER.COLS
VALUES('NUM_ENQ_ANO')
VALUES('NUM_ENQ_IDT')
VALUES('BEN_RNG_GEM')
VALUES('NUM_ENQ_IDT')
VALUES('BEN_SEX_COD')
VALUES('BEN_NAI_ANN')
VALUES('BEN_NAI_MOI');

CREATE TABLE SASUSER.TEST AS
SELECT (SELECT * FROM SASUSER.COLS)
FROM LIBERICO.IR_BEN_R_202107;
QUIT;
```

The error message is this one:

```
ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming by your tables name that you are interested in retrieving the columns that are in `COLS` from `IR_BEN_R_202107`. If that is the case a simple macro-variable should do the trick:

```
proc sql noprint;
select col into :cols separated by ", "
from cols
;

create table test as
select &cols.
from liberico.ir_ben_r_202107
;
quit;
```